# Unable to extract Text using VBA, when there are multiple Classname , tagname and attributes with same name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to extract the innertext under the 'span' class from a IE browser, but facing an issue.  Below is the HTML code

**1st html snippet**

```
<div class="SectionStart" style="display: block;" oraload="oraDisplayNone(item,'newDev','Y','=')" oraInitDisplayStyle="block">
  <label oramdlabel="CM_SN">Serial Number</label>
<!--style tag has been added-->
  <span class="oraDefault" style="left: -5px; top: 4.5px; position: relative;" orafield="MSerialNumber" oraType="string;precision:20" oraErrorElement="mSerialNumber">G4A001</span>
</div>
```

---

**2nd html snippet**

```
<div class="SectionStart">
  <label oramdlabel="CM_SN">Serial Number:</label>
<!--style tag has been added-->
  <span class="oraDefault" style="left: -5px; top: 4.5px; position: relative;" orafield="MSerialNumber" oraType="string;precision:20" oraErrorElement="mSerialNumber">E5W807</span>

</div>
```

Here the issue is as per below code ,while trying to fetch the 2nd value "E5W807", I am only fetching the not required value "G4A001".

Please guide how can I tackle the problem of ONLY extracting the text "E5W807".

```
 Set objSubCollec = objCollection(0).contentWindow.document.getElementById("Page")
    Set objElement = objSubCollec.contentWindow.document.getElementById("Frame_4")
    objElement.Focus
   Set objElement1 = objElement.contentWindow.document
   Set elm2 = objElement1.getElementsByTagName("span")

          For Each e1 In elm2
              If e1.getAttribute("orafield") = "MSerialNumber" Then
                 temp = e1.innerText
                'MsgBox temp
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B6") = temp
        Exit For
    End If
    Next
```

Comment: When it finds a `span` element that meets your criteria, you're instructing the code to exit the `For Each/Next` loop.  So it doesn't get a chance to loop through the remaining elements.  If you remove `Exit For`, it will loop through every `span` element.

Comment: There must be Multiple `"MSerialNumber"` in the complete document. So you need to print those in loop. As @Domenic said you are exiting the loop after first instance is found.

Comment: Not an answer, but a word of advice...  The indentation used for your VBA is rather inconsistent; you would be surprised how much of a difference proper indentation can make to reading code and spotting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Maybe Try this:**

It will print all the found numbers in succession from B6.

```
Set objSubCollec = objCollection(0).contentWindow.document.getElementById("Page")
Set objElement = objSubCollec.contentWindow.document.getElementById("Frame_4")
objElement.Focus
Set objElement1 = objElement.contentWindow.document
Set elm2 = objElement1.getElementsByTagName("span")


i = 6
For Each e1 In elm2
    If e1.getAttribute("orafield") = "MSerialNumber" Then
       temp = e1.innerText
       Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B & i") = temp
       i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint . I can now extract the required respective text .